# decrypt Android app TCP traffic using mitmproxy, frida, and wireshark

Tags: networking

I am trying to inspect traffic from a production Android app, which I don't control, on a rooted Android phone. I'm following the guide [here](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2022/04/mobile-mitm-intercepting-your-android-app-traffic-go), which basically uses [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and [frida](https://github.com/frida/frida) running on a Linux container on the Android device.

The app doesn't use HTTP/S, so I am trying to use Wireshark to inspect the raw TCP traffic. My Android device and my Mac laptop are connected to the same WiFi network.

- I started mitmproxy (on the Android linux container) with the `--rawtcp` flag. (latest verison 5.3.0 of mitmproxy)
- I also specified a `SSLKEYLOGFILE` in order to export SSL/TLS master keys
- command: `SSLKEYLOGFILE="$PWD/sslkeylogfile.txt" mitmproxy --mode transparent --rawtcp`

Then I start the app under investigation using the [Frida](https://github.com/frida/frida) dynamic instrumentation tools, and the frida universal android [ssl repinning bypass script](https://codeshare.frida.re/@pcipolloni/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-with-frida/):

- `frida -H 127.0.0.1 -f com.example.app -l frida-android-repinning.js`

Then I cat the sslkeylogfile.txt to terminal and copy it over to my Mac laptop. The file looks like this:

```
CLIENT_RANDOM 1234567890abcdef...2f
CLIENT_RANDOM f43c7a7b0c96b1b2...74
```

Then on my Mac laptop computer, I start the Wireshark GUI app, go to `Preferences > Protocols > TLS`, and set the `(Pre)-Master-Secret log filename` to the sslkeylog.txt file I just created.

Then in Wireshark I set a filter `ip.addr = 192.168.1.242`, corresponding to my Android phone's local IP, and start Wireshark.

Unfortunately when I click on any packets with the Source or Destination corresponding to my filter, the packets are still encrypted. I expected that they would have been decrypted into plaintext because I specified the sslkeylog.txt file.

[image]

How can I decrypt the traffic?

Comment: Does your log really only contains the CLIENT_RANNDOM? Because this seems to be not sufficient for TLS decryption: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/50305/how-does-wireshark-decrypt-ssltls-with-only-clientrandom/ Usually it is a a good idea to enable the TLS decryption log (set a file name in the same settings page where you specify the SSLKEYLOGFILE file). Otherwise TLS decryption just fails silently any you never know why.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there are only `CLIENT_RANDOM` keys in `sslkeylogfile.txt`. In the Wireshark TLS debug file, it shows some lines like `Cannot find QUIC CLIENT_EARLY_TRAFFIC_SECRET` ad also `decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder` and `decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available`. Not sure how to get these from mitmproxy

Comment: In my opinion your chances would be better if you directly extract the keys from the app and don't use mitmproxy at all. https://github.com/saleemrashid/frida-sslkeylog BTW: Mitmproxy latest version is 9.0.1 not 5.3.0. Your python version may be too old to get the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. FYI I upgraded my python and now have mitmproxy version 9.0.1. The sslkeylogfile.txt now contains these keys: `CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET,CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0,EXPORTER_SECRET,SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET,SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`. Wireshark is still not decrypting the contents though. I'll try the frida-sslkeylog method next

Comment: Also I do see lines like this in the ssl-debug.txt file now: `matched client_appdata, matched client_handshake, matched exporter, matched server_appdata, matched server_handshake`. Not able to get frida-sslkeylog working yet, it seems to fail to download frida rather than using my built version (which is for an arm64 architecture, google pixel 4 phone)